# YouTube API: Abort Resumable Upload

Tags: youtube-api

YouTube API Specification (https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_resumable_uploads) provides info about how checking the status and resume an incompleted upload.

But what about aborting a resumable upload? How long an incompleted upload can be resumed?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube API does not provide this information directly.
It just says that

> session URI has a finite lifetime and eventually expires
> https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol

Google Drive talks about a week

> A resumable session URI expires after one week.
> https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol
> https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads

Since the API is similar / same, it will be probably same